# Trying to run `dockerize` on Debian Stretch, getting python error: "TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding'", how to fix?

Tags: python, docker

I'm trying to run the `dockerize` command like so:

```
$ dockerize -o tools -n `pwd`/tools/usr/bin/my-tool
```

The command starts but generates an error:

```
WARNING:dockerize.dockerize:writing output to tools
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/dockerize", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('dockerize==0.2.2', 'console_scripts', 'dockerize')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dockerize/main.py", line 135, in main
    app.build()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dockerize/dockerize.py", line 130, in build
    self.resolve_deps()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dockerize/dockerize.py", line 208, in resolve_deps
    deps.add(path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dockerize/depsolver.py", line 113, in add
    self.get_deps(path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dockerize/depsolver.py", line 83, in get_deps
    elf = ELFFile(path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dockerize/depsolver.py", line 36, in __init__
    self.read_sections()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dockerize/depsolver.py", line 44, in read_sections
    encoding='utf-8')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 212, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding'
```

The same command works just fine under Ubuntu 18.04. What would be missing on Debian Stretch that `dockerize` fails like so?

Installation command:

```
$ pip install git+https://github.com/larsks/dockerize
```

Version of this Debian instance:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 9.13 (stretch)
Release:        9.13
Codename:       stretch
```

Version of python:

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.13
```

We also tried with Python 3.x and it generated the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `-m trace` command, I was able to find out that the command that failed was a process command which now accepts a parameter named `encoding`.

```
python -m trace --trace /usr/local/bin/dockerize \
      -o tools -n `pwd`/tools/usr/bin/my-tool 2>&1 | less
```

One example of a failing call:

```
        out = subprocess.check_output(
            ['objdump', '-h', self.path],
            stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
            encoding='utf-8')              // <-- this is the culprit...
```

*(from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dockerize/depsolver.py)*

The solution is to use at least [python version 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html).